# PHP Fetch MYSQL row and explode into array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, tags

My code searches through my table videos and finds any words LIKE $string and returns it in an exploded array but when I echo it out on screen it just shows ArrayArrayArray without showing it in plain text like I want.

I have tags inside my video_tags column for an example: cats dogs birds lizards and want to individually put them in an array to be used in another code for easy search on my site. If there is a better way of doing tags, tips would be very helpful but I havn't thought of anything else at the moment.

```
$string = 'cats';
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "media");
$getarray = "SELECT video_tags FROM videos WHERE video_tags LIKE '%$string%'";
$result = $db->query($getarray);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $str = $row['video_tags'];
        $token = explode(" ", "$str");

        foreach($token as $arr) {
            echo "$arr<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

If I instead added the code below I get somewhat what I am looking for but figured if I wanted to individually use my tags, an array would be more useful for me and I only know the explode function to do that.

```
$string = 'cats';
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "media");
$getarray = "SELECT video_tags FROM videos WHERE video_tags LIKE '%$string%'";
$result = $db->query($getarray);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $str = $row['video_tags'];
        $token = strtok("$str", "");

        while ($token !== false) {
           echo "$token<br>";
           $token = strtok(" ");
       }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `$row` is the full row, `$arr` are your exploded bits. Also don't quote variables. `"$str"` should just be `$str`.

Comment: Awesome, okay I got it now. Can't believe I over looked that. Kept redoing my code that I forgot to put $arr in place of $str